# com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: 2147467259

Tags: gwt

Am getting the below exception once the module is loaded in the browser. but the functionality is not blocking only getting 4 script errors similarly. Can anybody help on this?

```
13:47:07.196 [ERROR] [com.manoj.Account] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Unspecified error.
 number: -2147467259
 description: Unspecified error.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are the 4 script errors?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and stepping through your entry point code using the eclipse debugger?

Comment: @jason: description came in alert as "unspecified errors", but the functionality is not breaking!

Comment: @Eric: yes on debugging after adding the module in the root panel, the debug point goes to nativeMethodAccesor,BrowserChanelServer built in classes, exception not generated from my code written!

Comment: anybody can you help me on this?

Comment: Looks issue is locked - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5181

Answer (score 1):

Had the same thing here.  Resolved it by replacing the Image (`<img>`) with a Label (`<div>`) and gave it a background-image style property.   Adding and removing the Label from the dom does not throw the exception in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I am also got this exception, i resolved this. In my case i am removing image from parent while doing this in IE8 GWT runing a thread for changing the proeprites on the image that time it is throwing exception. so instead of removing i just made it hidden, it is resolved